# How to remove lines that begin with the same character?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to clean up the output from someone else's script by removing the headers that have no content.

Output currently looks like this:

```
====== Header1 ======
====== Header2 ======
====== Header3 ======
information
```

I'm trying to remove the lines for Header1 and Header2, but not Header3. I found an awk command that removes all duplicate lines but the last that begin with the same character, so that helps for this issue, but causes a new problem when the 'information' bit is numerous lines that also begin with the same character (usually tabs).

Desired output post cleanup:

```
====== Header3 ======
information
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem in its current form appears rather trivial.  Consider providing some bit of realistic data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The "Headers" are all component names that are unique, and the information is a git commit message that I'd like to retain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk might work for you:

```
$ awk '/^===/{h=$0;p=0;next}!p{print h};{p=1}1' file
====== Header3 ======
information
```

Or as Glenn pointed out, this also works:

```
awk '/^===/{h=$0;next}h{print h;h=0}1' file
```

Comment: +1 for the concept. You don't need 2 vars though: `/^===/{h=$0;next} h {print h; h=""} 1'`

Comment: @glennjackman You are correct. I guess the structure of the header guarantees that the `h` variable will not have a null value with a record.

Comment: Additional enhancement: skip header even if blank lines follow: `/^===/{h=$0;next} h&&!$1 {next} h {print h; h=""} 1'`